# how i can draw these shapes in adobe illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

This is a screenshot of a drawing from youtube and the designer was using Illustrator.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. We ***do*** ask that your question shows some *effort*: tell us what you already know and understood; show us what you tried and failed; document what you found when searching the manual - illustrate your question with sketches, screenshots or examples of what you have accomplished trying so far. Please read [ask] and revise your question - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

GDSE is not a tutorial on request site, but since you are obviously new to Illustrator, I will attempt to give you an idea on how you might proceed. The following is a simple method that could be used in Illustrator CC, not sure about CS6 since I no longer have a copy I can check to see if it has corner widget functionality. However there are many ways this could be done even if you are using an old version of Illustrator*. I'll let you decide if you think it's worth the upgrade.

You can begin by using the Pen tool to create straight sided shapes. Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you use the Pen tool constrains the angles. Also, switching on Smart Guides will also help you line things up.

[image]

Next, select the shapes using the Direct Selection tool (A). And select each corner widget in turn, and bend as required by clicking and dragging the corner widget.

[image]

*In older versions of Illustrator without the corner widget functionality, you will probably need to add additional curve anchor points and bend the Béziers manually.

[image]

Other possibilities include using rounded rectangles and the pathfinder Minus Front/Unite, or Shape Builder tool to combine shapes.

Here's an example using a regular rectangle, and some rounded rectangles and the Shape Builder tool

[image]

Comment: Maybe someone who uses CS6 will know if corner widgets are available in that version.

Comment: Should be its the primary addition of CS6

Comment: @joojaa - yeah, I just couldn't remember. 2012 is such a long time ago. Anyway, I updated the answer to include older verisions without corner widgets.

Comment: There's no corner widget in CS6, Billy. Joojaa is mistaken. It was introduced in CC2014 I believe. So.. VectorScribe, or circles and pathfinder/shapebuilder are CS6's best bet. (I still use CS6 daily and prefer it over CC versions).

Answer (score 0):

Try using pathfinder in windows menu...where you can combine or subtract 2 rectangles to get these shapes.
(or)
You can draw these using pen tool
(or)
even trace the image.